# Office-add in online sideload

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-js, custom-functions-excel

We followed the steps mentioned in "Sideload an Office Add-in on Office online" to work custom function for desktop or online users but still custom functions not appearing for both. Manifest file able to upload without any error but function not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

do you get a browser error? i.e. through the console? How are you hosting?

One common issue: you're using a self-signed certificate which is generated by the Office Yeoman generator, you'll need to trust the certifcate. Depending on your custom function project, if it doesn't show a taskpane, you can just navigate to the endpoint, i.e. https://localhost:3000/ and manually trust it.  Then sideload the manifest again.

Comment: Hi Keyur, Thanks for the update. I did IIS hosting and able to access the hosted url's without issues in browser.  Also sample Office JS application with taskpane able to install and view in excel online. But when I sideload manifest for custom functions tag and once installed not reflecting in excel online. When i trying to invoke the custom function after installed getting text as "#NAME?" in the excel cell. Kindly help.

Comment: Hi Muruga, I think we'll need more information to help debug your case. Can you fill out this form with your contact info and we can reach out to you?  https://aka.ms/customfunctionscall

Comment: Hi Keyur, I have sent mail id for which invitation to be sent with clarifications.

Comment: Sent you a mail to get addditional repro. We can reply back to this thread with results afterwards.